# Is my mainboard HAV compatible?

Tags: motherboard, virtualization, hardware-virtualization

How do I see if my Hardware-Assisted-Virtualization is compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Hardware-assisted virtualization (HAV), also known as accelerated virtualization, was added to x86 processors (Intel VT or AMD-V) in 2006. It allows multiple operating systems to simultaneously share processor resources in a safe and efficient manner. You can check if your CPU supports HAV by searching for the specifications of that model number CPU. You can find the specifications of an Intel CPU by searching for `ARK Intel CPU-model-number`.

In the motherboard's BIOS/UEFI setup utility the hardware-assisted virtualization setting is located in Advanced mode -> Advanced tab -> CPU Configuration -> Virtualization Technology or a similar navigation which is different for different motherboards, so you need to enter your motherboard's BIOS/UEFI setup utility and search for the hardware-assisted virtualization setting there.

Thinking ahead, the next consideration after HAV compatibility is if there is an SSD with enough free disk space to allow running a VM from the SSD in order to obtain improved performance.